What options (short of abdication) might a Queen or King of England have to avoid giving royal assent, formally turning a bill into law?
The BBC's April 23, 2024 Rwanda: Why a migrant plane won’t be taking off anytime soon contains the following:

While the bill has now passed through Parliament, the quickest a flight can take off is - technically speaking - 12 days after the King has given royal assent, which then formally turns the bill into law.

If the Queen or King finds some particular bill (the above is just an example) personally unconscionable, or contrary to the good of the people to an extreme extent, what options (short of abdication) might they have to avoid giving royal assent with the goal of preventing a bill from becoming law, or at least slowing it down and making if not a statement, at least a very visible gesture?

@EikePierstorff but causing constitutional crises seem to be so in vogue these days...

In this particular case (shipping people to Rwanda) there was another option by another body of the government (Lords) but wasn't used by them. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/86117/lords-powers-to-stop-a-bill-rwanda

Very closely related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/174/why-dont-british-kings-and-queens-veto-laws

@SteveMelnikoff in that particular case, the closing of that question with several very well received answers to it as a duplicate of the other might not have been the best decision. The other two options would be to 1) not close it (because closing potentially diminishes the visibility of those answers) 2) close the other one as the duplicate, and 3) merge the two (which isn't done very often). See comments and answers to Should we do anything to promote useful answers on duplicate questions?

@uhohdoIreallydictate I agree! I had no power over that decision.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84373/what-is-the-point-of-a-royal-assent

Nowadays Royal Assent (Wikipedia) is widely considered to be a formality and in normal circumstances (e.g. no public emergency) its outright refusal would provoke many people to wonder why the monarch has the right or power to veto legislation passed by Parliament.
An exception might be in the case of the Cabinet advising against giving Royal Assent. However, this has not occurred for three centuries.
Queen Anne refused Royal Assent to the Scottish Militia Bill 1708 on the advice of her ministers, who said there was a risk the militia would be disloyal, a risk heightened by the Franco-Jacobite invasion fleet en route to Scotland at the time.
In less fraught circumstances, what would be more likely is quiet words behind-the-scenes about the monarch's discomfort, before this stage were reached, and could something be done to assuage them in some way.
More recently, George V took legal advice as well as ministerial advice on withholding assent to the-then Government of Ireland Bill (aka Irish Home Rule Bill). He decided against refusal without "convincing evidence that it would avert a national disaster, or at least have a tranquillising effect on the distracting conditions of the time."
Of course, given refusal hasn't happened in modern times we can't say what would happen in reality, we can only speculate.
The abdication or death of the monarch doesn't solve the problem because the heir instantly becomes the new monarch. The absence of the monarch doesn't solve the problem because Royal Assent can be approved by certain Counsellors of State.
The monarch can order the Dissolution of Parliament. This would prevent the Bill's passage for some time, particularly if its opponents won a majority. By convention, of course, the monarch only orders Dissolution on advice from their Prime Minster.
Far more likely - but only in the context of the monarch's interests - legislation could be affected much earlier in the process by means of the King's Consent. This is a convention that requires consent when a proposed bill will affect the Crown's prerogatives or interests and there has been criticism that it has been used to allow the monarch to shape legislation. This has a practical advantage in that it avoids the controversy of refusal of Royal Assent by affecting legislation before that stage.
The Guardian published a table of affected Bills alongside its criticism - it's quite varied: Agriculture, Tenant Fees, Fire Safety, Pension Schemes, Data Protection, High Speed Rail, Energy, Small Business and Enterprises, Marine Navigation, Charities, etc.

I am not sure about how it would apply to the UK, but a few decades ago Baoudouin of Belgium did not want to approve an abortion bill.
The loophole he used was getting himself to be declared "temporarily incapacitated". This meant that a regency was setup. That regency did, in turn, approve the law.
After all had passed, then Baoudouin "suddenly" got better and got reinstated to his powers

There is a lesser known procedure known as Queen's (now probably King's consent) that can be used by the monarch to vet laws before they are approved by parliament.
Apparently the procedure applies only to laws that could affect the monarch's interests, so it is unlikely that it would apply to the Rwanda bill.
According to reports, this mechanism has been used in the past to:

Protect the Royal Family's wealth from scrutiny
Prevent police investigations on Royal property without consent
Exempt the monarch from anti-discrimination laws
Ban environmental inspectors from Royal property


How does the procedure work? The link only says it's opaque. Does the monarch really have a veto right with this or is it more like an additional round of consultation before being forced to give the royal consent? The monarch seems to have been able to exert quite some influence there but maybe this was only a courtesy of the respective governments.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution it's complicated - but I think it's an attempt to reconcile two things: "The Monarch's signing of bills should be a formality" and "Parliament has a duty to the Monarch, and should not make bills to harm them" - so, nothing formal about royal assent, but it's more an agreement to never get to the point where this could become a constitutional crisis.
